# What is Java EE Endorsed API?

Tags: api, maven, jakarta-ee, endorsed

See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax).

There are three different Java EE related API:s available in the Maven repository.

1. Specification APIs (*Maven artifact: javaee-api*)
2. Web Specification APIs (*javaee-web*)
3. Endorsed APIs (*javaee-endorsed-api*)

I know the specification API (the full blown suite of Java EE API:s) and the web API (a subset of the former, implemented by some application servers).

But what is the "endorsed API" and do I need to care?

Note: I did find [this link](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/index.html) but it tells me nothing.

Comment: There are a lot more Java EE APIs available in maven than three. Those are just collecting APIs - usually you would prefer individual APIs, like servlet api, EJB api etc.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18356334/269514) might help.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be GlassFish related. Download the jar and execute:

```
jar -tf javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar
```

Actually, if you look at the table in the "Standalone Technologies" section of that [link](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/index.html) you referenced, there seems to be a very good correspondence between the classes included in the javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar and the items in the table. I would say it seems that the jar is bundling up these for GlassFish so that the jar can be dropped into

```
<java-home>/lib/endorsed
```

And then become available to applications deployed on the GlassFish server.

Comment: To anyone like me that had no idea what "-tf" does: `t` says "list table of contents" and `f` says "next we'll provide you with an jar file". So `-tf` displays the contents of the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems running a project because of this dependency in NetBeans. Installing "EJB and EAR" plugin solved it for me.