# Recource injection doesn't work with glassfish 4 while lookup works

Tags: jsf, glassfish, datasource

I use resource injection in my application scope managed bean with glassfish 4, but glassfish failed to work and using the default derby database instead. there is my code:

```
@Named(value = "dbManager")
@ApplicationScoped
public class DbManager {
  @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydb")
  private DataSource ds;
```

// but lookup method works

```
 ctx = new InitialContext();
 ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
```

I can't find the reason for this.

Comment: post yur faces-config and web.xml

Comment: Andy, I read [Trouble injecting resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422577/trouble-injecting-resources-with-java-ee-6-and-glassfish-3-1-using-resource). and replace @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydb") with @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/mydb") and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 @Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/mydb")
```

instead of this

```
 @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydb")
```

It works for me on glassfish 4. :)